# Perl interpreter for Windows

Tags: windows, perl

Perl interpreter for windows:

- Must run natively (e.g. no CYGWin etc...)
- Must support a large chunk of CPAN libraries (meaning you can download them prebuilt, like PPMs from ActiveState).
- Must refresh reasonably quickly with new Perl versions (e.g. support at least Perl 5.16 and ideally 5.18 by end of 2013).

Comment: BTW, ActiveState fails the 3rd bullet combined with 2d - as of Jan 2014, their 5.18 is basically non-functional since they have almost no PPMs for it, yet.

Answer (score 6):

I think at this point, [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) is the one to go with.  While historically vanilla perl was more up to date (due to simplicity in testing a minimal bundle) that's no longer an issue and vanilla perl appears dead.

I have significant experience with Strawberry Perl (and before that Vanilla Perl) and so here's how it fits into your bullet points.

1. This is a native build.
2. While it does not come with pre-built libraries outside of the core libraries, `CPAN::Bundle`, and a few others, it comes with a complete build environment based on Mingw.  My general experience is that most CPAN modules work out of the box and you can install them just by running something like:  `cpan Wx` (and have it download, compile, and install `Wxperl` and `Wxwidgets`).  There are however some modules I haven't been able to make run properly (`LaTeX::Driver`, for example, fails make test with what look like harmless issues comparing paths, and `Template::Latex` doesn't seem to work even if you force install).  Those are a relatively small minority though.
3. Currently, 5.18 is supported, with 5.16 available as well.

So I am not quite sure whether this meets your needs.  If you have to support most of CPAN and find a build environment to be intolerable, you probably need to look elsewhere, but if having a good, tested build environment is good enough, I would highly recommend it.   It is the one I go to any time I need to deploy a Perl application on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Use [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). It's native and has CPAN and everything else you'll need built in. If you want precompiled modules, you can run ActiveState Perl alongside it and use modules from either. (See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694119/why-is-it-discouraged-to-use-ppm-perl-modules-with-strawberry-perl-on-windows).)

Comment: How does it fit bullet #3? Does it come with precompiled CPAN libraries available like PPMs?

Comment: You can install both ActiveState Perl and Strawberry Perl and use both CTAN and the available precompiled PPMs, filling bullet #3 as best as possible. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694119/why-is-it-discouraged-to-use-ppm-perl-modules-with-strawberry-perl-on-windows).

Comment: To be honest, if you don't mind using the fully functional build environment that comes with it, you will have better CPAN coverage with Strawberry Perl than you ever will with ActiveState.